# How to implement K-max pooling in cntk?

Tags: cntk

Has anyone implemented K-Max pooling in CNTK? It is a max-pooling layer that, rather than selecting the top one out of some number of units, selects the k largest outputs from all the units in the previous layer.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has not been implemented yet. We are making a note of it. Happy to take in contributions.